# Mono error format exception but not on windows

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, mono, formatexception

Any reason why I get this error on Mono but not on Windows?

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Invalid format string
at System.DateTime.ParseExact (string,string[],System.IFormatProvider,System.Glo                                                                                                          balization.DateTimeStyles) <0x00127>
at System.DateTime.ParseExact (string,string,System.IFormatProvider,System.Globa                                                                                            lization.DateTimeStyles) <0x0004f>
at System.DateTime.ParseExact (string,string,System.IFormatProvider) <0x0001f>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.CallSite.Target (System.Runtime.CompilerServi                                                                                        ces.Closure,System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,System.Type,object,string,S                                                                                        ystem.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo) <0x000f3>
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4<System.Type, object, string,                                                                                         System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo, object> (System.Runtime.CompilerServic                                                                                            es.CallSite,System.Type,object,string,System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo) <                                                                                                0x00418>
at TwitterScraper.Program.scrapeTwitter () <0x00a22>
at TwitterScraper.Program.Main (string[]) <0x000bf>
```

using this code here

```cs
DateTime tweettime = DateTime.ParseExact(obj["created_at"].ToString(),
        "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss %K yyyy",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

This is used to deal with the time format Twitter gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
DateTimeOffset tweettime = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(yourInputString,
    "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```